# Object does cast shadow, but doesn't get physically darker

Tags: modeling, texturing, shadows

I have modelled a stool, and textured it, however, when a light it shone onto the object, it casts a shadow as intended but the object itself doesn't get darker.

Here is a file with the stool I've made and the textures used:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Id3lPOutqwnDUSGzUA8RlaTLruxY6V7I?usp=sharing

And an image too:

[image]

Edit: Turns out the normal map is creating this issue, once disconnected in the node editor, the object darkens. Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going on. I downloaded your files, I opened the file, I had to go to External Data - Find Missing Files, but that's just because I moved them, I think. Either way, without changing anything else, this is what I get:

[image: Shadows]

So, I'm not sure if there's something wrong with your version of blender, or graphics drivers or whatnot, but it seems fine on my end.  For testing purposes, as well as easier shareability, I am including the .blend file in this post with the textures packed.

File is here - [image]

If you're still having problems, one thing I can recommend is to swap the sun lamp for a large area light - I always find it casts better shadows and doesn't give such uniform brightness, but that's just me.

Hope this helps.

EDIT - Because you mentioned the normal being a problem, I looked closer at it and noticed your normal map is connected through a `Normal` node, as opposed to a `Normal Map` node as it should be.  I have included an image below of the correct node setup, for reference.

[image: NodeArrangement]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found that disconnecting the normal map in the node editor fixed it for some reason. Don't understand why it does this, normal maps I've used on other objects in the scene I'm creating don't do this.

Comment: Actually, when I used "Find Hidden Files", the only error it gave me is that it couldn't find the normal map. I connected it manually, and it looks the same. I'm not sure what happened, but evidence does point towards the normal map, I definitely agree.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed I missed something BIG - when you connect the normal do it through the `Normal Map` node, not `Normal`. Also, connect the output from the `Normal Map` node to the normal input of your `Displacement` node.

Comment: Thank you again, going to have to do this to all my shaders now, strange that I've not had this issue with other objects setup in the exact same way.